# What are these windows/portholes on the English Electric Canberra bomber?

Tags: military, feature-identification

This may be an obvious question, but I don't know, which is why I'm asking here. I've searched "Canberra canopy porthole" and "window", but didn't get any information. There is a porthole of sorts on the left side of the canopy of this bomber, I'm wondering what it's for.

[image]
[Photo source.](http://www.airpowerworld.info/bombers/english-electric-canberra-cockpit.jpg)

Here is a view from inside the cockpit:

[image]
[Photo source.](https://www.haraldjoergens.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/english-electric-canberra-virtual-tour-screenshot-cockpit-large.jpg)

There also appears to be a similar thing on the bottom of the nose of the aircraft, offset to its right. The following is a screenshot from a video game, as I wasn't to find a photo of this.

[image]

I'm tempted to say that this second one is to do with bomb sighting, however if it weren't there, the bomber would have just as good a view, wouldn't they?

Comment: A blown, spherically shaped plexiglass dome will never have the optical qualities of a flat piece of glass, especially with the production technology of the late Forties. So yes, the nose cone window is for bomb aiming.

Comment: You beat me to it w/ your comment Peter-- was in process of adding to my answer

Answer (score 10):

It's called a "Direct Vision" (DV) window. The canopies are sealed shut, so the small DV window is provided as a way to open a small hole if required. For example, to communicate on the ground or in the event of icing or other canopy issues.

Edit: I wasn't able to find a formal source, but this page is fairly authoritative:

http://alverstokeaviation.blogspot.com/2016/08/english-electric-canberra-technical-tour.html

Comment: Note the wires going to it-- it is heated, don't you think?  If it opens, can you identify where the handle or latch is?  So perhaps it is heated AND it can be opened?

Comment: Is this both the case for the canopy one and the one on the lower nose? Would you open the port/window completely? If so I'd imagine enormous amounts of wind entering the cabin. @quietflyer Yes, I did notice the wires. Not sure what they're for.

Comment: @quietflyer It certainly makes sense to be heated. It looks pretty clear that the bottom is hinged (7 O Clock our image), with a secured (thumbscrew) handle at the top (1 O Clock)

Comment: I'm thinking that part of the reason it exists, is so it can be heated more strongly than the plexiglass could be.  In other words it is glass and can take the direct heat of a heating element that would melt the plexiglass.  This answer could be improved by incorporating that idea.

Comment: That's a very interesting link. In that model the bottom flat window seems to be for bomb sighting. It is also centred, as opposed to the offset ones to the side in my images.

Answer (score 7):

Re the upper "porthole"-- it sure looks like a heated panel for clear vision in extreme icing.  Note the resemblance to a "hot plate" in King Air etc.  It is undoubtedly glass and can be heated by a heating element (note the wires) to much higher temperatures than the perspex canopy could tolerate.  Note that there is one on each side, and this aircraft has side-by-side seating in the cockpit.  As has been noted in another answer, it appears to have a hinge and a thumbscrew latch, so it could be opened if needed (e.g., a/c is heavily iced up and electrical power has been lost or can't keep up with the icing-- or just to talk to someone on the ground.)

Your question also references the flat panel on the transparency on the lower part of the nose.  It is not clear from the photos whether this is heated or not; it's almost certain that this larger flat panel could NOT be opened.  However you'll note that it is very common for aircraft to include a flat glass panel for aiming a bombsight or as a window for a camera in the case of a reconnaissance aircraft.  The curved perspex of the rest of the transparency will always have some optical distortion.  Note that until fairly recently, many fighter aircraft had a flat windscreen in front of the pilot.  Again part of the reason for this was to prevent optical distortion as the pilot looked through the gunsight.  If this weren't an issue, the thick armored flat glass of the windscreen could have been "faired" more smoothly by an additional curved piece of perspex in front of it, but this was only rarely done.

Comment: I'm not a Downvoter, however, *"Probably a (guess)"* is a very poor answer.

Comment: Well, I don't think so.  Anyone who's seen a "hot plate" in a King Air etc would note the strong resemblance but it's only appropriate to note that one doesn't actually know this for a fact.

Comment: If we are waiting for a design engineer or pilot to provide a definitive answer we might be waiting a long time.  A credible, well reasoned educated guess goes a long way towards generating useful discussion and enhancing understanding.

Comment: Was starting to type the additional info as saw your comment Peter

Comment: This is a good answer now. It also answered another question that was in my mind, why do fighter aircraft have a flat glass front portion on the canopy given that it sacrifices aerodynamics. I think maybe because it's usually thick bulletproof glass, but the view distortion reason seems true also.

Comment: @quietflyer I did not downvote, but a person can only downvote once, regardless of how many times the answer has been edited. As of me writing this, this answer has +3/-2.

Comment: Clicking the "up" or "down" button on a post you've already voted on will remove your vote, not add a new one. You can only remove your vote or change an upvote to a downvote (or vice-versa) within a certain period of time or when the question is edited, you cannot vote multiple times.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that the vote can be CHANGED after an edit but an additional upvote/ downvote cannot be ADDED after an edit.  Thank you for the clarification.  That is a good system and I'm glad it's that way.  I am going to delete my comments re that issue.

Comment: This is begging for an answer to why other jet aircraft don't have it (it could be included in this answer).

Comment: Good point-- I've got to go do something else now but....

Answer (score 4):

I was a Canberra pilot back in the day.  The porthole in the canopy was simply a way for the pilot to see his way if the canopy misted or iced up, simple as that.  In fact I never had to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: Hi. Was it the only part that was heated? Any supporting information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The panel in the nose cone was a piece of optically flat glass to avoid distortion which would affect the bomb site, and/or to give a camera a clear view forward.

Answer (score 0):

the DV window was used by aircrew , open the dv and stick your hand out, to indicate to the ground crew that the aircraft in now depressureised and that it was safe to open the side door (strike wing RAF Akrotiri)

Comment: Hi. Can't they just see a thumbs up from behind the canopy? (There must be something else to it, preferably with a reference to back up any claim.)